# C++ error array displaying

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   char unknown [10] = {0987,12,124,436,564,345,565,678,197,69};

   for (int x=0; x<10; x++;)
   {
       int RR = unknown[x];
       cout << RR;
   }
}
```

I got like 4 errors and 1 warning (which I think I am not supposed to)I have no idea why. Here are the 4 errors

```
8|error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
10|error: expected ')' before ';' token
10|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
10|error: expected ';' before ')' token
8|warning: unused variable 'unknown' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: All of these errors are obvious, trivial, and they indicate that you didn't make the slightest effort to learn the language yourself using a beginner tutorial.

Comment: Hello, @Alien, and welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask programming questions and other readers try to answer the questions. I note that your post does not contain any questions.  Do you have  specific question to ask? If so, plese edit your post to include your question. For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user3477950 I have tried to find some good tutorial on how to learn the language I even posted a question if anyone has any good starting way to properly learn the book. Perhaps a book or a website. But the question got denied

Comment: The question was denied as it was too broad a topic. This site is for specific problems people have with actual code. For wider questions about programming in general you may freely use [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), [computer science](http://computerscience.stackexchange.com) and other more appropriate forums.

Answer (score 4):

A constant starting with 0 is expected to be octal in c++. Thus `0987` is not a valid constant (because there are no digits `9` and `8` in octal) and that is what the error says.

Second problem - there is no semi-colon before the closing bracket of `for`:

```
for (int x=0; x<10; x++ /*no semi-colon */)
```

Comment: Also, why is there a semi-colon after `x++` in the for loop?

Comment: @user3477950 just added that

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now I have 14 warnings and 3 errors

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the semi-colon --' I still dindn't do exactly what I wanted to do but I think I can fix it